# TI's bypass mode step-down converters

Tags: voltage-regulator, rf, buck, converter, ldo

Texas Instruments encourages the use of the [TPS62730](http://www.ti.com/product/TPS62730) step-down converter with bypass mode along its RF devices. Does this mean :

- its noise is low enough not to affect RF ? Thus being a more efficient solution than an LDO ?
- using 3.0-3.6V devices and a 3.0-4.2V battery, the converter could be bypassed when battery hits 3.6V and efficiency would become 100% ?